# AJAX & jQuery $.getJSON(...) throws XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This could be another "I'm dinosaur" question, but I'm just starting with `front-end` stuff.

So I built application which returns me `JSON` via `URL`:

```
http://localhost:8080/json
```

and this returns:

```
{"id":41,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

dev tools:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/json
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Well I've managed to create "web application" with following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/json", function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

When i launch it I can see on a console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/json. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Why on earth this thing don't want to cooperate. What m I missing here?

Comment: If the page's host name does not match localhost:8080 exactly then you will get an XMLHttpRequest exception unless you properly set up CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)

Comment: simply run your **html file** from your **localhost** (or from other host in that matter).. that will solve it :)

Comment: XMLHTTPRequests are subject to the same origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Thanks guys for this quick response !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your "Webapplication" is not hosted under `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` than the webserver on localhost:8080 needs to allow you to do XMLHttpRequest.
This must be done by the HTTP Header Access-Control-Allow-Origin (which can also contain * for every site or an url of your "Webapplication")

Comment: Since I used Spring to create that, I should provide it somewhere in the back-end?
Besides that, code looks good?

Comment: For testing I would recommend to put the html file also on the webserver that serves the json, rest should work.